# When is the supremum of one set equal to the infimum of another set?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets of real numbers.  My question is, under what circumstances is the supremum of $A$ equal to the infimum of $B$?

Now $x$ is the supremum of $A$ if and only if for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $a\in A$ such that $x\geq a>x-\epsilon$.  And $y$ is the infimum of $B$ if and only if there exists a $b\in B$ such that $y\leq b<y+\epsilon$.  Is there any way to combine these two conditions into a single condition for when the supremum of $A$ is equal to the infimum of $B$? Some kind of inequality involving elements of $A$ and elements of $B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to ask for something like $$\forall a\in A\forall b\in B(a\leq b)\wedge\forall \epsilon\exists a\in A\exists b\in B (a\leq b\leq a+\epsilon),$$
which actually means that $A$ is below $B$ as a set and thee two sets have elements that are arbitrarily close. But I am not sure if this exactly what you are looking for.

Since every element of $A$ is below $B$, the supremum of $A$ $x$ cannot be above the infimum of $B$ $y$, i.e. $x\leq y$. But if we had $x<y$, then say using $\epsilon=|x-y|/2$, we cannot find any element of $B$ at distance less than $\epsilon$ from $x$ (and so from every element of $A$), contradicting the formula above. This proves that the formula above implies that $x=y$.

On the other hand, if $x=y$, given any $\epsilon$, we can find $a$ and $b$ with distance from $x$ less than $\epsilon/2$. In particular, $a\leq b\leq a+\epsilon$. Moreover, clearly every element of $A$ is not above $x$ and every element of $B$ is not below it, so the formula follows.

Comment: This is indeed the kind of thing I'm looking for.  But is it correct?

Comment: It is. I will edit my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: So is it a necessary and sufficient condition?

Comment: Yes it is. I added the proof.

Comment: OK thanks for your answer.

Comment: Wait, shouldn't the first part be $\forall a\in A\forall b\in B(a\leq b)$?  Like what if $A=B={1}$?

Comment: You are right, that might be the case. Thank you for the remark

Comment: Can you take a look at my follow-up question here? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2972629/71829