# Approximating Darboux integrals with continuous functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function.  Show that the upper Darboux integral of $f$ is equal to the infimum of the Riemann integral of $g$ over all continuous functions $g\geq f$.

I'm not sure how to approximate an arbitrary bounded function with a continuous function.  One thought I had is that that upper Darboux integral is itself an infimum, namely the infimum of upper Darboux sums.  So we are basically trying to show that the infimum of two sets are equal to each other.  But I'm not sure what the conditions are under which two sets have the same infimum, though my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2972629/71829) is relevant to that.

Comment: There are different ways to define the Riemann integral; could you give the definition which you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P = (x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and upper Darboux sum $U(P,f)$ such that

$$\overline{\int_a}^b f \leqslant U(P,f) < \overline{\int_a}^b f + \epsilon/2$$

Note that the upper Darboux sum is the integral of a step function $\phi_P = \sum_{j=1}^NM_j \mathbb{1}_{[x_{j-1},x_j)}$ with $M_j = \sup_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]} f(x)$, that is

$$U(P,f) = \int_a^b\phi_P = \sum_{j=1}^NM_j (x_j- x_{j-1})$$

For each point $x_j$ we can take a small interval $[x_j- \delta,x_j]$ and straight line joining $(x_j-\delta,\phi_P(x_j- \delta))$ and $(x_j,\phi_P(x_j))$, thereby constructing a continuous, piecewise linear function $g$ such that $f \leqslant \phi_P \leqslant g$ and $0 \leqslant \int_a^b (g - \phi_P) < \epsilon/2$.  We then have

$$\overline{\int_a}^b f \leqslant \int_a^b \phi_P = \int_a^b g - \int_a^b (g-\phi_P) < \overline{\int}_a^b f + \epsilon/2$$

Thus, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a continuous function $g \geqslant f$ such that

$$\tag{1} \overline{\int_a}^b f \leqslant \int_a^bg < \overline{\int_a}^b f +\epsilon$$

It is easy to show that for $\mathcal{G} = \{g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} \, | \, g \geqslant f, \, g \text{ continuous}  \}$, we have

$$\tag{2} \overline{\int_a}^b f \leqslant \inf_{g \in \mathcal{G}} \int_a^b g,$$

since upper sums of $g$ dominate upper sums of $f$.

A strict inequality in (2) would contradict (1) which shows there exist continuous functions $g \in \mathcal{G}$ such that $\int_a^b g$ is arbitrarily close to $\overline{\int_a}^b f$ (as $\epsilon \to 0$).

Thus,

$$\overline{\int_a}^b f = \inf_{g \in \mathcal{G}} \int_a^b g$$

Comment: I do not want to make an unsolicited edit here, but I think `\overline{\int_a}^b` looks better than `\overline{\int}_a^b`, especially when there's an `\int_a^b` nearby.

Comment: Why do (1) and (2) together imply the result?  In other words why does (2) imply that the upper Darboux integral is greater than or equal to the infimum over $G$ of the Riemann integral of $g$?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: If we have strict inequality $ \overline{\int_a}^b f < \inf_{g \in \mathcal{G}} \int_a^b g$ then we have a contradiction with (1) which shows there are continuous functions $g$ where $\int_a^b g$ is arbitrarily close to $ \overline{\int_a}^b f$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. Thus we must have equality in (2).

Comment: The result (2) follows because for any partition $P$ if $g \in \mathcal{G}$ then $\overline{\int_a}^b f \leqslant U(P,f) \leqslant U(P,g)$ .  Taking the infimum of the RHS over partitions we get $\overline{\int_a}^b f \leqslant  \inf_{P} U(P,f) \leqslant \int_a^b g$.

Comment: @David K: Thanks for the suggestion -- I edited and it does look better.

Comment: Also, is it possible to use this result to prove the counterpart result, namely that the lower Darboux integral of $f$ is the supremum of the Riemann integral of continuous functions less than or equal to $f$?

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan: Yes, the argument is similar for the lower integral.  In the end these results hold because Darboux upper and lower integrals are the infimum and supremum, respectively, over step functions which can be as closely approximated as we like in the L1 norm by continuous functions.

Comment: What I’m asking is, without redoing the entire proof, can you just use the result about upper Darboux integrals directly to prove the result about lower Darboux integrals?

Comment: Yes. Just replace $f$ with $-f$,  use that $U(P,-f) = -L(P,f)$.